# Spring Eclipse (STS) @RequestMapping view is blank, is it because of Maven projects?

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc, ide

I'm using STS 2.7.2 for an existing Maven project. The web app runs perfectly fine in Tomcat. The structure is as follows:

1. core
2. service
3. web
4. war

So that's effectively 4 projects by Maven. I have added Spring project nature to all 4 and added the bean configurations (xml) for each project, however the Spring Tools > Show RequestMapping is still blank. I have tried triggering this command in all 4 project's config including the war's config set web-context.

I'm just wondering if anyone else may have similar project setup and has successfully viewed the RequestMapping functionality in STS?

Comment: Are you using @ModelAttribute? If so check if your command class has a default constructor.

Answer (score 1):

To see anything in RequestMappings `view(@RequestMappings)` do the following: right click on project or config file(applicationContext if you have one)>properties>Spring

In config files, select your bean configuration file.